# Expand recurrence and CalendarDate:Event EndDate not autocalculated for recurring events

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, calendar, recurring

I have done the following code to save a recurring entry to Calendar List named `Bookings`.

```
    SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url);
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists["Bookings"];
        SPListItem recEvent = list.Items.Add();
        try
        {
            recEvent["EventDate"] = startdate;//11/09/2012 08:00:00
            recEvent["EndDate"] = enddate;//11/09/2012 08:30:00
            recEvent["Booking_x0020_Title"] = Convert.ToString(txtTitle.Text);
            recEvent["Title"] = Convert.ToString(txtTitle.Text);
            recEvent["RecurrenceData"] = Recur_Xml.ToString();//ReccurrenceRule
            recEvent["fRecurrence"] = "True";
            recEvent["EventType"] = 1;
            recEvent["UID"] = System.Guid.NewGuid();
            recEvent["TimeZone"] = 0;
            recEvent["Recurrence"] = -1;
            recEvent["XMLTZone"] = "<timeZoneRule><standardBias>-330</standardBias><additionalDaylightBias>-60</additionalDaylightBias></timeZoneRule>";

            recEvent.Update();
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {

        }
```

If i save the above with Recurrence rule as `Repeat every 1 day for 10 occurences` than the Item is saved properly and Current Events view shows all the instances but while fetching the Recurring entry i get only 1 Result i.e on Start Date. The following is the Code to retrieve recurrent values:

```
SPWeb oWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
                SPList oListBookings = oWeb.Lists.TryGetList("Bookings");
SPQuery oQueryBookings = new SPQuery();

                            string strQuery = "";
    strQuery = @"<Where><DateRangesOverlap><FieldRef Name='EventDate' /><FieldRef Name='EndDate' /><FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' /><Value Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value></DateRangesOverlap></Where>";
                            oQueryBookings.ExpandRecurrence = true;
                            oQueryBookings.Query = strQuery;
                            oQueryBookings.CalendarDate = date;
    SPListItemCollection oCollBookings = oListBookings.GetItems(oQueryBookings);
```

The result is shown only if `oQueryBookings.CalendarDate = date;` equals `11/09/2012 08:00:00` and it does not return any items for Dates after that even when the instances are present for these dates till `19/09/2012 08:00:00`

The query returns all the item if i set the `recEvent["EndDate"]` to `19/09/2012 08:00:00` while saving the item. I want the EndDate for recurring items to be set to same day on user form (`no user would want to calculate the last date of his occurence for recurring pattern with no end date`) and it should be autocalculated on save.How is that possible?

If I make the entry using sharepoint UI than this End date is autocalculated even if it is set to the same day and if its a recurring entry.

Please guide where am I going wrong? Is it while saving or while fetching the records? Or is it because the `EndDate` is the same date as `StartDate`? Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Check "**fRecurrence**" and "**Recurrence**" fields. You can try to use "1" instead of "True" and I am not sure about "Recurrence" == -1. Could you please clarify what does it mean?

One more idea. You can create recurred event, using SharePoint Site, to test your second part of code.

As I know for recurring events with **no end date**, "EndDate" is a computed date several years in the future. So if your code is correct, to handle recurrence events, you should update "EndDate" by appending additional years.

Comment: Thanks. `EndDate` for an event which occurs after every 2 months only on sunday and end after 10 occurences! how will i get the enddate of such an event? My issue is not with the events with no end date, i can append many years in future and it works fine. My issue is only with events repeating for certain instances.

Comment: Ok. For repeating instances you should check a RecurrenceData. The xml value should contain a "repeatinstances" tag with a number of instances. For example, if you want that event would be ended after 10 occurrences, the xml value should be like this:

<recurrence>
  <rule>
    <firstDayOfWeek>su</firstDayOfWeek>
    <repeat>
      <monthlyByDay day="su" weekdayOfMonth="first" monthFrequency="2" />
    </repeat>
    <repeatinstances>10</repeatinstances>
  </rule>
</recurrence> 

Please check attributes in the "monthlyByDay" tag.